# How do I properly dismiss an alert in JavaScript with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I am using Cucumber.js and Selenium Webdriver on Node.js.

I am testing a page that has an alert pop-up when the page loads - it asks for permission to use the user's location which I have disabled in Firefox, so an alert appears advising the user that a default location will be used.

The problem I am having is that although I seem to (visually) be able to dismiss the alert all successive test steps have the error:

```
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: Dismissed user prompt dialog: Some alert text...
```

Try as I might I cannot figure out how to get rid of this. I have tried:

Setting an option when I build the browser:

```
let options = new firefox.Options();
options.setAlertBehavior(UserPromptHandeler, 'dismiss');
options.setPreference('geo.enabled', false);
this.driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();
```

Dismissing it in a Cucumber step:

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
});
```

And this way (as per Selenium docs):

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent());
    let alert = await this.driver.switchTo().alert();
    await alert.dismiss();
});
```

I've also tried waiting before dismissing:

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 3000 });
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
});
```

And

```
When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.sleep(3000);
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
});
```

But the issue remains.

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this?

My full code:

```
const { When, Then, Given } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const { Builder, By, until, Key } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Options } = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const { UserPromptHandeler } = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/capabilities');

Given('I am on the branch locator page', async function () {
    let options = new firefox.Options();
        //options.setAlertBehavior(UserPromptHandeler, 'dismiss');
        options.setPreference('geo.enabled', false);
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(options)
        .build();
    
    this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('h1')));

    await this.driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com');    
});

 When('I dismiss the alert', async function() {
    await this.driver.sleep(3000);
    this.driver.switchTo().alert().then((alert) => alert.dismiss());
});

Then('I click the radio button', async function() {
    await this.driver.findElement(By.id('option2')).click();
});
```